# What should the praja (citizens) do if their ruler is adharmic?

Tags: dharma, kings

Are they suppose to endure it ? Or they should collude with a dharmic king to overthrow him ? While there were quite a few evil kings - from Ravana to Kamsa, I am unsure of their behavior towards praja. I am more interested in knowing if there were kings who were cruel towards their praja. In such scenario what should the praja do.

Looking for an answer supported by scriptures.

Comment: Not from scriptures, but going by the lore surrounding Chanakya, seems they should plan to overthrew adharmic kings or system in their personal capacity in detached way.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27797/was-there-a-process-of-impeachment-if-a-king-was-found-to-be-in-violation-of-dha/27800#27800

Comment: If you are interested, you may check this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58681/24460, I have cited śāstras which support the action of subjects overthrowing an unjust ruler. Thanks