# What does hindu scripture say on following law and order which sometimes is bad and against ethical and moral reasons?

Tags: scripture

What does hindu scripture say on following law and order?

I want to know that is there anywhere written in hindu scripture to boycott law and kill lawmakers when law is discriminatory and colonial .

Also, I want to know what do scripture say on tolerating law when it is opposite to scripture like allowing adultery, smoking, alcohol , drugs etc.

I want to know if law persecutes an innocent person .Can he use weapon and arms against state?
Are there conditions given in which conditions is it justifiable to attack the state in scriptures?

Ps:looking for a detailed and well explained answer

Comment: This is a duplicate question [Was there a process of impeachment if a king was found to be in violation of dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27797/was-there-a-process-of-impeachment-if-a-king-was-found-to-be-in-violation-of-dha)

Comment: You may check this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58681/24460, I have cited śāstras which support the action of subjects overthrowing an unjust ruler. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In general terms, the Mahanirvana Tantra chapter 8 (https://sacred-texts.com/tantra/maha/index.htm) says:

> The householder should thus also cherish and protect his brothers and sisters and their children, his kinsmen, friends, and servants (48). He should also maintain his fellow-worshippers, fellow-villagers, and guests, whether ascetics or others (49). If the wealthy householder does not so act, then let him be known as a beast, a sinner, and one despised in the worlds (50). The householder should not be inordinately addicted to sleep, idling, care for the body, dressing his hair, eating or drinking, or attention to his clothes (51). He should be moderate as to food, sleep, speech, and sexual intercourse, and be sincere, humble, pure, free from sloth, and persevering (52). Chivalrous to his foes, modest before his friends, relatives, and elders, he should neither respect those who deserve censure nor slight those who are worthy of respect (53). Men should only be admitted to his trust and confidence after association with them and observation of their nature, inclination, conduct, and friendly character (54). Even an insignificant enemy should be feared, and one’s own power should be disclosed only at the proper time. But on no account should one deviate from the path of duty (55). A religious man should not speak of his own fame and prowess, of what has been told him in secret, nor of the good that he has done for others (56). A man of good name should not engage in any quarrel with an unworthy motive, nor when defeat is certain, nor with those who are superior or inferior to himself He should diligently earn knowledge, wealth, fame, and religious merit, and avoid all vicious habits, the company of the wicked, falsehood, and treachery (58). Ventures should be undertaken according to the circumstances and one’s condition in life, and actions should be done according to their season. Therefore, in everything that a man does he should first consider whether the circumstances and time are suitable (59). The householder should employ himself in the acquisition of what is necessary and in the protection of the same. He should be judicious, pious, good to his friends. He should be moderate in speech and laughter, in particular in the presence of those entitled to his reverence (60). He should hold his senses under control, be of cheerful disposition, think of what is good, be of firm resolve, attentive, far-sighted, and discriminating in the use of his senses (61).
>
> The wise householder’s speech should be truthful, mild, agreeable, and salutary, yet pleasing, avoiding both self-praise and the disparagement of others (62). The man who has dedicated tanks, planted trees, built rest-houses on the roadside, or bridges, has conquered the three worlds (63). That man who is the happiness of his mother and father, to whom his friends are devoted, and whose fame is sung by men, he is the conqueror of the three worlds (64). He whose aim is truth, whose charity is ever for the poor, who has mastered lust and anger, by him are the three worlds conquered (65). He who covets not others’ wives or goods, who is free of deceit and envy, by him the three worlds are conquered (66). **He who is not afraid in battle nor to go to war when there is need, and who dies in battle undertaken for a sacred cause, by him the three worlds are conquered (67)**. He whose soul is free from doubts, who is devoted to and a faithful follower of the ordinances of Shiva, and remains under My control, by him the three worlds are conquered (68). The wise man who in his conduct with his fellow-men looks with an equal eye upon friend and foe, by him are the three worlds conquered (69). O Devi! purity is of two kinds, external and internal. The dedication of oneself to Brahman is known as internal purity (70), and the cleansing of the impurities of the body by water or ashes, or any other matter which cleanses the body, is called external purity (71).

Comment: This (included the bolded statement) doesn't exactly answer the question of the OP, looks more of as a random post you have put up. You are an old member, I would assume that you do know that the answers shouldn't be random in nature, and should be specific.